# is there any other way of creating an object without using "new" keyword in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the different ways to create an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java)

as we can create array object without using "new" keyword as example. just curious to know whether we can create any other type of object without using "new" keyword.