# creation of object

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there any other way of creating an object without using “new” keyword in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103089/is-there-any-other-way-of-creating-an-object-without-using-new-keyword-in-java)

how many ways are there to create an object in java ?

Comment: why? ...................

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103089/is-there-any-other-way-of-creating-an-object-without-using-new-keyword-in-java/2103146#2103146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Using reflection
Class classObj Class.forName("Foo");
Foo obj1 (Foo)classObj.newInstance();

//new operator
Foo obj2 new Foo();

//cloning
Foo obj3 (TestObjectCreation)obj1.clone();

//deserialization
ByteArrayOutputStream baos new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(obj1);
ByteArrayInputStream bais new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream ois new ObjectInputStream(bais);
Foo obj4 (Foo)ois.readObject();
obj4.method1();
```