# Java class instantiate

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the different ways to create an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java)

what are the different ways that i can instantiate a class in Java other than new operator?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new object through reflection. Example:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("Foo");
Foo foo = cls.newInstance();
```

Other methods are cloning and deserialization, as you can see in the answers of this question: [What are all the different ways to create an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java/95428#95428)