# In how many ways can we create an instance of an object?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the different ways to create an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java)

In how many ways can we create an instance of an object.
Please explain each way.