# Object creation in Java

Tags: java, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the different ways to create an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java)

How many ways to create an object in java? I was asked about this in a recent interview.

Since everything in Java is on the heap, I would think 'new' is the way to go. Comments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/22478 answer from jkathiravan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 ways off the top of my head(I know this because I too was asked this question once!):

**Using new:**

```
Car obj = new Car();
```

**By Cloning:**

```
Car a = new Car();
Car b = a.clone();
```

**Using forName from Class**

```
Car obj = (Car) Class.forName("Car").newInstance();
```

**By Deserializing:**

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(instream);
Car object = (Car) in.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

`new` definitely, reflection is another option