# How to store data from specific library in main application - Java

Tags: java

I'm very new learner in Java and currently having a hard time in understanding the concept of library and main. I'm trying to store the input of user in the specific library which is Store without adding "static". Is my logic wrong? Here's my code

```
    package app;
    import Library.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Enter 1 if you want to store name data \nEnter 2 if you want to store age data ");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = scan.nextInt();
            
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    System.out.printf("Name: ");
                    Store.name = scan.next();
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    System.out.printf("Age: ");
                    Store.age = scan.nextInt();
                    break;
            }   
        }
```

Heres my library code

```
    package library1;
    public class Store {
        public String name;
        public int age;
        public Store(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Save user input in variables and then call `new Store(name, age);` however, you can get the same information by googling faster than asking here

Comment: [How to create object of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609960/how-to-create-object-of-class) - this should help to get started.

Comment: Please study a tutorial or textbook on the basics of Java before posting here. Oracle provides a tutorial online free of cost. See [*Creating Objects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned if you want to use switch case for same `Store` object, but if we assume its for same `Store` object, then you can do :

```
Store store=new Store("", 0); //initialize with no name & zero age.

switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    System.out.printf("Name: ");
                    store.name = scan.next();
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    System.out.printf("Age: ");
                    store.age = scan.nextInt();
                    break;
            }
```

This will either set name or age but not both.

One more tip, `import library.Store` is required in your `Test` class.