# Object and references in java

Tags: java, reference

I am confused as I am new to java, how many objects and references are created in the following piece of code?

```
MyClass t = new MyClass();
MyClass s = new MyClass();
MyClass v = s;
```

Please explain the answer:

```
2 Objects
3 References
```

Comment: Psst: Java is case-sensitive. MYclass != MyClass != Myclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A picture is worth more than a thousand words:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An object is an instance of a class, created with `new`.  You use `new` twice, so there are two objects.<sup>*</sup>

A variable is, generally speaking, a reference.<sup>**</sup>  So there are three references (`t`, `s`, `v`), although two of them happen to refer to the same object.

---

<sub>* Of course, `MyClass` itself might create more objects internally.</sub>

<sub>** Except in the case of primitive types, like `int`, `float`, etc.</sub>

Comment: ok.. so u mean to say that v and s are reference to same mem location.?

Answer (score 2):

2 Object and

3 reference

if you do `new` you are creating object so there are two new so simply two Objects

and if you define

`Foo a;// you have just created a reference`

<sub>* Note: `new` is only a way to create object, it can be created using otherways too</sub>

Comment: What are other ways to create an object other than `new` (not including things like `clone` which will call `new` internally?)

Comment: @Oli http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 2):

So you are creating a new object and storing a reference to that object in `t`. The same for `s`. Then you are assigning the `s` reference to `v` (not creating a new object). So you have three references and two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your answer is wrong. It's the other way around:

> 2 objects (in the first two lines)
>
> 3 references (t, s, v, v and s share an object)