# Object creation in java with out execute the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

Normally a constructor will execute when will we create a object for a class. but my question, is it possible to create a object with out executing a constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488097/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-an-object-in-java-without-calling-the-co

Comment: There are loads of ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607261/instantiate-objects-without-using-new-operator

Comment: Maybe look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488097/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-an-object-in-java-without-calling-the-co

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Please do a little search before asking such questions.

Comment: If you want to construct you have to construct (i. e call constructor either *explictly* via `new` or implicitly via *reflection* etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Without any byte code manipulation and dirty hacks, no matter what, your constructor always executes on Object creation. If you do not pass any args, it will surely invoke your default constructor.

You are wanting to live in a home, without building it ;)

Comment: `clone` and `ObjectInputStream#readObject` are not really dirty. At most slightly shady...