# Is show() method Static method or not?

Tags: android-studio

I had seen that the Toast in android->

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

From seen that, I think that **makeText** a static method and **show** method non-static method.

But after that seen->

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

I am get confused.
How show() is called without creating an object of Toast class?(If **show** method is non-static-according to first code)

Comment: `You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle`

Comment: Yeah I know that. But i have no sufficient reputation for giving feedbacks.

Answer (score 2):

The two pieces of code you show are the same.

The second one calls `Toast.makeText(context, text, duration)`, takes the return from that (the Toast instance) and calls `show()` on it.

The first code block makes a local variable called toast but the behavior is the same in both.

Answer (score 1):

[Show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#show()) is not a static method. Show() can be called because [MakeText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) returns a Toast object.

Comment: I have question about that-> 1. How to create a object without using "new" keyword(First explanation)?   2.  It's confirm that makeText method is static otherwise I am not calling a method without creating an object. In addition that my next question is -> then how to call show method without creating an object(Second explanation)?   In addition I am new in java. If you have any refence doc regarding this then it's very easy for me.

Comment: 1. [Have you checked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607261/instantiate-objects-without-using-new-operator) 2. MakeText() creates Toast object. Because of that you can call `Toast.makeText().show()`. It seems like that you are not familiar with static methods. I would advice you to read about static methods or look up a tutorial.