# Deleting a Node from the tail in a circular linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

The code that I'm trying to understand is below

```java
public void deleteNodeFromTail() {
    System.out.println('\nDeleting Node ' + tail.element + ' from Tail');

    if(tail.next == tail) {
        tail = null;
    }

    Node newTail = tail;
  
    while(newTail.next != tail) {
        newTail = newTail.next;
    }

    newTail.next = tail.next;
    tail = newTail;
}
```

How exactly is this deleting a node from the tail in a circular linked list?

I have a linked list of `[50, 75, 100, 25]` and I walked through this step by step:

The first step says that `if (tail.next) == tail`, `tail = null`. In this case 50 isn't equal to 25, so that would be skipped.

`Node newTail` is declared and is assigned whatever the value of tail is, which is `25`. The issue here is that I don't know what `newTail` is doing or how it's relating to the other nodes in the list. It looks to be a temp variable to hold a value, but I don't know the significance of why another node is being declared here.

Next, `newTail` is made equal to `newTail.next` as long as `newTail.next` isn't equal to `tail`. Again, I don't know whether `newTail`, should be considered part of the list, or the significance of `newTail` beyond being a temp variable to assign a value to another part of the list. I'm assuming that `newTail` is now part of the linked list, so we have `[50, 75, 100, 25, 25]`. This doesn't make sense.

From there I don't know what to do. The while loop seems like it would be an infinite loop. I'm also not seeing where the deletion itself happens, or how that's possible just by assigning values without actually decrementing the list.

Comment: that is conditional code if there is only one node in the entire list. That means the tail is pointing to itself (tail.next == tail). newTail is basically capturing the current tail without changing the node tail points to. (newTail.next != tail) is basically if this is not a one item list do x

Comment: How does this work though? Is newTail an alternative pointer to the value in tail? As far as my understanding of this goes, newTail just copies the value of tail, it doesn't actually point to it. newTail.next wouldn't point to the whatever value in the list that tail.next would.

Comment: java doesnt use pointers. Java is pass-by-value, and in this case, it passes a reference by value, and following this reference, newTail finds the tail object, and looks for tail.next. But you also have another major misunderstanding. Why do you think they are pointing towards the value? they are pointing towards the next Node

Comment: basically, the while loop says: "if what comes after my current newTail variable is not the tail, i update newTail so that it stores the reference of the object that comes after the original newTail" This keeps happening until the newTail variable is the object that comes before tail

Comment: newTail.next is a variable that is supposed to point to tail, but your statement `newTail.next = tail.next` means take the variable that newTail is supposed to point to, and replace it with what tail is pointing to. meaning newTail now no longer points to tail

Comment: I guess my confusion was thinking that newTail=tail meant that newTail was only copying the value of the tail node like as is the case with other variables. I didn't realize that two nodes would literally become the same and that both tail and newTail were referencing the exact same object.

Comment: new objects are created with `new`. If there is no `new`, there is no new object (there are  [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607306/5459839)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know "how exactly [this is] deleting a node from the tail", and I don't have any reason to believe that it does. You can post any nonsensical code and ask us to figure out why it does what you allege it does, but the first question is, does it actually do that?

The following lines:

```
    tail = null;
}
Node newTail = tail;
while(newTail.next
```

will, on occasion, cause a null pointer exception at `newTail.next`.  So, this code is highly suspicious. So, unless you tell us where you found it, and why you believe it does what you allege it does, we have no reason to look at it any further.