# Object creation syntax in Java

Tags: java, syntax, jvm, jvm-languages

Regarding syntax for object creation using `new` keyword. I know that syntax to create an object is:

```
Foo ref = new Foo();
```

Do java language in itself provide some mechanism that can create object other than standard syntax as mentioned above?

I have knowledge that Scala has such functionality or may be some other JVM compatiable language but I want to know from just core java point of view.

Without using keyword 'new' and assignment operatior '='. For example it can be like Foo ref Create(). ? Now I want to develop 'Create' method to replace traditional syntax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java

Comment: The assignment operator has **nothing** to do with an object's **creation**.

Answer (score 4):

Another way you can create an object is by reflection:

```
Foo ref = Foo.class.newInstance()
```

Comment: you are right but I was thinking like someway without using keyword 'new' and assignment operatior '='. For example it can be like  Foo ref Create().

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are looking for:

> Different ways to create objects in Java
>
> This is a trivia. Yeah, it’s a bit tricky question and people often get confused. I had searched a lot to get all my doubts cleared.
>
> There are four different ways (I really don’t know is there a fifth way to do this) to create objects in java:
>
> 1. Using new keyword
>      This is the most common way to create an object in java. I read somewhere that almost 99% of objects are created in this way.
>
> MyObject object = new MyObject();
>
> 1. Using Class.forName()
>      If we know the name of the class & if it has a public default constructor we can create an object in this way.
>
> MyObject object = (MyObject) Class.forName("subin.rnd.MyObject").newInstance();
>
> 1. Using clone()
>      The clone() can be used to create a copy of an existing object.
>
> MyObject anotherObject = new MyObject(); 
>   MyObject object = anotherObject.clone();
>
> 1. Using object deserialization
>      Object deserialization is nothing but creating an object from its serialized form.
>
> ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(anInputStream ); 
>   MyObject object = (MyObject) inStream.readObject();
>
> Now you know how to create an object. But its advised to create objects only when it is necessary to do so.

Source : http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/different-ways-to-create-objects/

P.S: I copied the text from the post, so that it is visible even if the link goes down. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Excuse at the bottom notwithstanding, this is still plagiarism.

Comment: The link can die, and to make this answer independent of it. I have copied the text, with sources mentioned in it. This is clearly not plagiarism.

Comment: Just mentioning the source is not enough: making your answer nothing but a copy-paste, with no contribution of your own, is plagiarism just as well.

Comment: @SalmanAyub Don't worry, the answer is still here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5104630/1587046

Comment: There's no plagiarism here; it might not be proper SO procedure, but the answer credits the author of the original and only quotes a reasonable length of it.  Absent SO practice, there's nothing improper about it.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.newInstance()` using reflection API eg.

```
Foo ref = Foo.class.newInstance();
```

Please read the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) on Class API. Go for [Spring Dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/beans.html), it will help you.

This [page](http://javapapers.com/spring/dependency-injection-di-with-spring/) can give you a good start

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am looking or thinking about flexibility as far as object creation is concerned. Foo.Class.newInstance() still binds me to predefined syntax. I am looking more flexibility, which adheres to java syntax but gives the power to customize the object creation process at my own will.

Comment: Then I believe you are looking for Dependency injection - Object creation by the framework based on the configuration

Comment: @Octopus I doubt he is looking for DI, more like DSL's and custom syntax

Comment: @om-nom-nom yeah, you are right! may be i am wrong. From the OP, it was difficult to undestand

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using the `new` operator in most of your code by creating a static factory method on your class:

```
class Foo
{
    public static Foo create()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Then instantiation looks like this:

```
Foo f = Foo.create();
```

This is not much more concise, however it does have several advantages as detailed in section 1 of Effective Java: it allows type inference of generic types (`Map<String,String> m = Maps.newHashMap();` instead of `Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();`), and allows you to change the method in the future to e.g. memoize the objects instead of creating a new object on each call.