# Creating an object reference for a java class without invoking it's constructor

Tags: java

I'm interested to know that, is it really possible to create an object reference for a java class without invoking any of it's constructors? If yes, how?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Even when you create the instance via reflection, the default constructor is invoked.

Comment: `Object myObject = null;` --> IS this what you would be looking for?

Comment: It might be possible with `sun.misc.Unsafe`. But in "normal" Java, it's not possible.

Comment: "an object reference for a java class" - the object should refer to the `class` or to be an `instance` of the class ?

Comment: @Eran It is possible by using JNI. Check my answer for a reference.

Comment: @Laf that's a `null` reference, it's not an object.

Comment: Related: [what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a bad idea, but you could use the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class to allocate an instance:

```
public static class TestClass {
    int field = 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Constructor<Unsafe> constructor = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe unsafe = constructor.newInstance();

    TestClass test = (TestClass) unsafe.allocateInstance(TestClass.class);
    System.out.println(test.field);
    System.out.println(new TestClass().field);
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by using JNI.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

**Object Operations**

*AllocObject*

```
jobject AllocObject(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz);
```

> Allocates a new Java object without invoking any of the constructors for the object. Returns a reference to the object.
>
> The clazz argument must not refer to an array class.

---

It is hard to find any relevant usage of it. I would not use it but it is still an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can think of is using the `clone()` method

`Object objectA = objectB.clone();`

Now `objectA.clone() != objectA` and `objectA` and `objectB` point to two different places in memory so technically you create an object without calling its constructor.

Comment: What if the class does not implement `Cloneable` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  Every class has a default constructor that calls its parent constructor super() which boils down to Java's Object Class.

Comment: Not true you can override default constructor to be private

Comment: Yes but there is always a constructor!

Comment: Can't create an object without calling some constructor either (default called implicitly) or your own created constructor called explicitly.

Comment: Technically, it is possible, obviously not through reflection. Still there's no real need to create an object by not using a constructor.