# Benefits of Avoiding 'new' Keword When Creating Object in Java

Tags: java, oop, instance, instantiation, object-create

I have found some blog where there is a suggestion of avoiding **`new`** keyword while 
creating object of a class. Some examples of creating object without the **`new`** keyword are-

```
SampleObject obj = Class.forName("com.example.SampleObject").newInstance();
```

Or using `clone()` method -

```
SampleObject obj1 = new SampleObject();  
SampleObject obj2 = obj.clone();
```

Then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java) I have found some good examples of creating object without **`new`** keyword

I can understand the advantages of 'Factory' pattern while avoiding **`new`** keyword from main portion of code. If I am not using any design pattern (for creating objects) is there any benefit of creating object without the **`new`** keyword? Or what are the reasons for creating of object without **`new`**?

Comment: I think, it's all about `static` method for creating objects. Something like `Paths.get` for standard library.

Comment: Then how are you planning to create object? Aren't you going to pass string to create object that you would use to load your class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you read in the blog must have been about factory methods and similar techniques, which don't *avoid* `new`, but rather place it behind a more flexible API.

There are definetely no overarching downsides to the `new` operator. It has been, and will remain, the staple of any Java code, and the most natural way to actually create an object, as opposed to satisfying a more generic concern, such as "provide me with an entry point to your API".

All other techniques that create objects without involving `new` are special-purpose tools (cloning, deserialization, etc.).

Comment: The other techniques must be *less efficient* right?. I mean under the hood, they must all be doing what *new* does internally. I was going through the java source code of `newInstance0()`, there is a lot of code in there :). Does any other techninque provide better performance than `new`?

Comment: Since `new` is the target of the most aggressive optimizations by the runtime, including Escape Analysis with the prospect of not allocating the object at all, it is basically impossible to get more efficient than `new`. As always, use standard idioms and enjoy the benefits of the optimizing monster that HotSpot has become.

Comment: Actually, you could get more efficient than new...by pooling instances.

Comment: @Andres The context is "more efficient at *creating* instances".

Comment: Yeah, agree. However, I think that stating that "there are definetely no overarching downsides to the new operator", is a bit misleading. I've seen many problems resolved only by replacing new by something different (singletons, DI, pooling, etc.)

Comment: @Andres Ripped out of context, any statement is misleading. This question is *about* object creation, and my answer reiterates that.

Answer (score 2):

**Complex Objects**

In general you may consider avoiding `new` for reasonably complex objects with non-trivial creation. You can consider some factory/builder which add versatility.

For example if you create a big composite object it is good to use builder pattern. 
([Long example here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398606&seqNum=5))

**Simple Objects**

For simple objects (most common case) it is best to stick with `new`.

For example if you have simple class

```
public class Dog{
    private string name;

    //getter + setter
}
```

Then it is an overkill to create factory for this and you should call it by `new Dog()`

**Dependency Injection**

In enterprise applications you commonly use dependency injection, which let's you avoid using `new` explicitly. You won't remove all object instantiations, but it provides nice improvement. 
([Basic Spring tutorial here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm))

Comment: The simple/complex dichotomy may not be that fruitful. A lot of very simple value-objects are backed by memoizing factories.

Comment: Most rules of design are not strict. You need to use some common sense which creates exceptions to them. You are right. That's not "definitive guide", but rather a guidance.

Comment: I already implied that in my comment (when I used the term *fruitful*).

Comment: Good. We have the same opinion then :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use Class.forName, the class name can be set at runtime. That can be useful for drivers e.g.

When you use new, instead, the class name of the instance you're creating is hard coded. In general, this creates high [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)), and should be avoided (Except when  you're absolutely sure you'll always need this coupling).

In short, **if you want to create an instance of a specific class**, `new` makes no harm.

However, you should ask yourself:

- If you really need a new instance (Otherwise, you should replace `new` by a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or a pool).
- If you'll always use the same class for that instance (Otherwise, you should replace `new` by [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))).

Answer (score 1):

there is no replacement for `new`, even `Class.forName("XYZ").newInstance()` *HAS* to work exactly like `new`, the only difference being that you're hardcoding the full class (or even `package...class`) hence actually achieve the **opposite** of what you're trying to do, with `new` the instance may be dynamically resolved and/or even injected.

If you inject an instance of `interface A` you may very well get a bean of class `B` which implements `A` - thats in fact more dynamic and complements factory patterns very well. Thats hardly possible if your classname is hardcoded, at least in my humble opinion.

Comment: When you use Class.forName, you don't have to hard code the class name. nor package. In fact, that's the main reason for using Class.forName.

Answer (score -4):

If you like sluggish, slow code, that is hard to debug, maintain and understand, absolutely, avoid using `new` keyword at all costs, obfuscate as much as possible!

Comment: shhhh! Dont you spread thruth on all the young "programmers" and "hackers" out there! They dont like that!

Comment: For creation of objects which require external resources, more subcomponents your "not obfuscated" code will take 20 lines in every place when object is created. It's better to have these 20 lines in single place and not to repeat them all the time.

Comment: of course - but that wont remove the need for `new` in your factory   .

Comment: @MarcinSzymczak, huh? Put the 20 lines where you want ... What are you talking about?