# Conversion of BigInteger to BigDecimal without new Operator

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

How can I convert `BigInteger` value to `BigDecimal` without using `new` operator?

For instance, if I have an integer value like:

```
abc=4000.
```

I should get the output as:

```
xyz= 4000.0
```

Comment: you can't create a *new* BigDecimal without using the *new* operator (or if there is a way, then a new BigDecimal *will* be created anyway - you just won't see it)...

Comment: no, you cant. Look at the answer below. It is impossible to create objects without `new` in java.

Comment: It depends on what `without using new operator` means. No use in own code or no use in internal code.

Comment: You cannot convert, you need to create new `BigDecimal` instance. About creating objects without `new` operator read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `valueOf` if you mean that your own code should not use `new` operator.

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(abc.longValue());
```

if `abc` is a `BigInteger`.

If you want to create the object without using `new` in your code and in the code of the jre then you **can not** do it. `BigDecimal.valueOf()` uses new to create a BigDecimal object.

Comment: @assylias Yes internally this funktion will do it. But I think the meaning of OP's question is that he will not use it in this code.

Answer (score 0):

**No you cant,** you can do it only with primitive types, everyting else is an object and has to be instantiate by using `new` operator. It might use it "under the hood" in example wrapped in factory method like `valueOf` `for BigDecimals`  but it will be still using it.