# Determine number of objects created in Java

Tags: java

Are objects created only when the `new` keyword is used? How many objects have been created once this code reaches the comments? I am saying 4 new objects because the constructor calls `new Exception()` each time a `Car` is initialized. How do I verify the number of objects created?

```
class Car {
    Car() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Do Nothing");
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car carOne = new Car();
        Car carTwo = new Car();
        Car carThree = carTwo;
        // how many objects have been created? 4?
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? I've seen this on exams before...

Comment: `new` isn't the only way to create objects and therefore isn't a reliable counter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java In your case it works though, yes 4 objects are created here.

Comment: The exception will probably create a stack trace internally, which may create an arbitrary number of stack trace elements...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no (at least not to my knowledge) automatized way of counting how many objects were created in java. In your example, however, there are 4 objects being created, 2 Exceptions and two Cars.

If you wish to count how many objects are for a given class, you can have a static counter that is incremented each time an object is created.

Edit: you can count created objects using `jmap`, as pointed out by Andreas, although it is a not very practical solution

Comment: You could alter the *Java virtual machine* to count the number of malloc operations, etc.

Comment: @CommuSoft You could recreate the universe to bake an apple pie... :D

Comment: The Virtual Machine upgrade is called AspectJ or something.

Comment: Yes. When you make Car carThree = carTwo; there is no actual place in the memory for a new Car, nor a new Car object has been created

Comment: Just to add, the carThree reference would be on the calling thread's (in this case: the main thread) stack since that would be a local variable pointing to the Car object in the heap that was previously created.

Comment: You *can* count objects created using `jmap`. Answer is `6214` on my machine, though that's not the answer the question is intended to elicit.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `jmap` and `jhat` to get a memory dump of the JVM.

Adding a `Thread.sleep(20000)` at the comment will make the program wait 20 seconds for you to execute the following commands. Increase wait time if needed.

In one command prompt, run your program:

```
java -cp . Car
```

In a different command prompt, during the the 20 second wait, run

```
jps
jmap -dump:file=C:/temp/x.dmp 99999
jhat C:/temp/x.dmp
```

Where `99999` is the process id listed in the output from `jps`.

The `jhat` program starts a web server on port `7000`, so go to:

```
http://localhost:7000/
```

Click on "Show instance counts for all classes (excluding platform)", and you'll see 2 objects only:

```
2 instances of class Car
```

That is because you excluded the `Exception` class from display.

If you clicked on the "... (including platform)" link, you'd see a lot of objects, with something like this:

```
Total of 6214 instances occupying 8071681 bytes.
```

If you implement your own exception, e.q. `CarException` and throw that instead, you'll see 4 "user" objects created:

```
2 instances of class Car
2 instances of class CarException
```

**So, which answer is correct? 2, 4, or 6214?**
Likely the expected answer is 4, as in "How many object did *your* program create?".

---

As for question of whether objects are only created when the `new` keyword is used, the answer is **No**. There are many other ways (e.g. listed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103578/5221149), and here are a few, with comment for number of objects created by the construct:

```
// Using "new"
new MyObject()      // 1 + number of objects created by constructor
new int[0]          // 1
new int[10]         // 1
new int[] {1,2,3,4} // 1
new int[10][]       // 1
new int[10][20]     // 11 (1 outer array + 10 inner arrays)

// Not using "new"
int[] x = {1,2,3,4} // 1
Integer x = 1       // 1  <-- autoboxing
printf("", i, j)    // 3 (autobox of i + autobox of j + varargs array)
String x = "a" + i  // 3 (StringBuilder + String + array backing String)
Integer[][] x = {{1111},{2222},{3333,4444},{},{}} // 10 (1 outer array + 5 inner arrays + 4 Integers)
```