# Constructor invocation bound to new keyword in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, profiling, new-operator, invocation

I'm working on Java Code Profiling where I need to know how many times a method has invoked a constructor in source code. So far the easiest way is to scan for **new** keyword and count that how many times constructor has been invoked. I would like to know is there any possibility where a constructor can be invoked without the **new** keyword?

Also if I'm only scanning for **new** keyword and binding it with constructor invocation only, it is possible that **new** keyword can also be used for some other purpose besides constructor invocation? (in that case my constructor invocation count could be wrong if such statement occurs in code)

Edit: I want to increase the count when any constructor is called.

Comment: Superclass constructors.  They can be called implicitly, or they can be called with `super(...)` from a subclass's constructor.

Comment: I don't think this should have been marked as a duplicate.  This question asks whether a constructor can be called without `new`; the other question asks how an object can be called without calling a constructor.  Two different things.

Comment: On the other hand, this [see my previous comment] normally happens only if you use **new** on some subclass of the constructor.  I'm not completely clear on what you're asking: do you want to know when any constructor is called, or do you want to know when a particular constructor is called?  And if you call a constructor and that calls another constructor (implicitly or with `super`), do you count that as two?

Comment: Im interested to know when any constructor is called. Yes that would be two constructor calls if constructor calls another super constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible through Java Reflection API and other ways as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java).

> There are two reflective methods for creating instances of classes:
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance() and Class.newInstance().
>   The former is preferred.

Described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html