# What is timerSeekBar in this java code an object or variable?What is findViewById,

Tags: java, android, view, android-seekbar, findviewbyid

I checked `findViewById` is a method so what is `timerSeekBar`, an object or a `variable`,got told its a variable but we are calling methods with it so it should'nt it be an object.Please explain why are we writing `SeekBar` before `findViewById`.

```
SeekBar -Class,findViewById- Method ?,timerSeekBar- variable or object?

SeekBar timerSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.timerSeekBar);

timerSeekBar.setMax(600);
timerSeekBar.setProgress(30);
```

another eg-

```
TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `findViewById` returns an instance of the class that is actually used to define that view in your XML file. 
(Seekbar) is used to cast that view with specific view.

You have to cast that(`findViewById`) to the class that your variable is defined when you use it.
So, This is the reason for

```
SeekBar timerSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.timerSeekBar);
```

From API 26, findViewById uses inference for its return type, so you no longer have to cast.

Please check below reference link  : 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/SeekBar.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.1_r1/core/java/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java

ProgressBar is super class, AbsSeekbar is Child class of Progressbar and SeekBar is childclass of AbsSeekbar.

setMax() is method of Seekbar and setProgress() is method of Progressbar.

Comment: Is timerSeekBar a variable or an object?

Comment: timerSeekBar.setMax(600); and timerSeekBar.setProgress(30); - function call made by the variable.Currently i know only objects can only make function call.Here findViewById is a method and as mentioned getting assigned to the variable after being casted to SeekBar type.So typically timerSeekBar is a method and is calling other methods,please explain

Comment: timeseekbar is instance of Seekbar.

Comment: setMax and setProgress are methods of Seekbar class.

Comment: Seekbar extends AbsSeekBar which have synchronized method setMax().

Comment: Check my updated answer. Hope it will help you to understand.

Comment: instance therefore its an object?Please detail on this

Comment: Yes, Instance means object of that class. So you can access it's method using that object. Java is object orient programming language.

Comment: but u said its a variable,what is it an object or a variable?

Comment: That's my mistake. It's an onject.

Comment: Okay thanks,what is this way of object creation called?

Comment: This is called intitalization. you can create object of class on different way. this link may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5104630/3364266

Comment: Was checking the exact same link but could'nt identify what type of initialization it is?

Comment: This is simple giving reference of that view.

Comment: I got that,what is this type of object creation ?Its an object right?

Comment: You can create object of class on different way.

Comment: Still to identify what way it is getting created in this case.Any clues would be great

Comment: This is concept of android. R.id.timerSeekBar is fetching id of view that is associated with view in xml. On Compilatation time, R.java file will generated.

Comment: "findViewById is a method of the View and Activity classes.This method will take a resource id usually in the form of R.id.mView and will return an object that is a reference to that View.Note that the referenced object needs to be cast to the correct type of View before you can start interacting with it"   -   So method is creating an object for me and this is one of the ways of creating object as u mentioned.I believe this is more like it.

Comment: Is anything more you want to know about? I hope my explanation helps you for understanding.

Comment: Yes i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

SeekBar is a widget.. It is defined in a file SeekBar.java ..essentially it is a `View` in android. Seekbar extends the base class `View.java` eventually. `findViewById()` method is used to find a `view` in android with a particular id set for the `view` using the `setId()` method. 
We use `SeekBar timerSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.timerSeekBar);` so as to tell the system that we are looking for a view using `findViewById()` method and then casting the base `View.class` type object to a subclass `SeekBar.class` type object. `(SeekBar)` is used to tell the system that this `view` is an instance of `SeekBar`.

Comment: Thanks,timerSeekBar is an object right? Widget as in like a package (pardon a  noob)?

Comment: yes... see when you are basically writing `TimerSeekBar mySeekBar` then you are creating the object of the class TimerSeekBar with name mySeekBar.. then you can access the methods of the class using objectName.methodName()...

Comment: Thanks, In this TextView timerTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView); TextView's an widget too? is Widget like a package,a collection of code like a set of classes?

Comment: it is a collection of code.. You will find code of TextView.java file if you hold the `ctrl` key and click on TextView.. You will understand. 
PS- If my explanation has helped you..please mark my answer as accepted.