# Initializing objects in Java without declaring a class or using a class

Tags: java, python, object

I have general question regarding objects in Java. I want to initialize an object in Java without declaring a class or using a class.

In python for example you can do like this:

```
myObject = {"x":5,"y":10,"z":12,"name":"something"}
```

Now **myObject** is an object. And I can say myObject.x which will be 5.

From what I know I would have to do like this in Java:

```
class object(){
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
   String name;
   myObject(int x, int y, int z, String name){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.z = z;
       this.name = name;
   }
}

myObject = new object(10,5,12,"something")
```

I would like to do that, but like in my python example.
Hope anyone can help :)

Comment: *"And I can say myObject.x which will be 5."* No you can't. You're thinking of JavaScript. (Though I guess in JS you'd have to omit the quotation marks around the keys.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey OP presumably meant `myObject.get('x')`.

Comment: You are both right. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is statically typed so you can't point a variable to an instantiated object without declaring the class.

You can create classes without a pointer but they will just be collected by the garbage collection machine unless you're passing them to something that uses the new object you're creating.

This is nothing in Java:

myObject = {"x":5,"y":10,"z":12,"name":"something"}

Java doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not python, and you cannot instantiate a Java object with an anonymous `Dict` (the only type of object you can instantiate with a syntax ***like*** that is an array). That is, this

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
```

is legal in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create an Object in Java without implicitly or explicitly calling the constructor and this involves creating a class which provides the blueprint for objects. (exception is by using deserialization)

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java) for all the possible ways of creating Objects in java